# TensorFlow: Compute Hessian matrix (and higher order derivatives)

Tags: python, matrix, tensorflow

I would like to be able to compute higher order derivatives for my loss function. At the very least I would like to be able to compute the Hessian matrix. At the moment I am computing a numerical approximation to the Hessian but this is more expensive, and more importantly, as far as I understand, inaccurate if the matrix is ill-conditioned (with very large condition number).

Theano implements this through symbolic looping, see [here](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/scan.html), but Tensorflow does not seem to support symbolic control flow yet, see [here](https://github.com/samjabrahams/tensorflow-white-paper-notes/commit/156736904eb48a0a44de4c23b227ae938e37e654). A similar issue has been raised on TF github page, see [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/675), but it looks like nobody has followed up on the issue for a while.

Is anyone aware of more recent developments or ways to compute higher order derivatives (symbolically) in TensorFlow?

Comment: Higher order gradients in TensorFlow/Theano are similar -- differentiating gives you an expression and you can differentiate again to get higher order derivative. If dimensions are known during graph construction time, you can use regular Python loop instead of control flow ops to concatenate partial derivatives into Hessian matrix

Comment: ok great, I was not sure about whether normal python control flow would work

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, you can , with little effort, compute the hessian matrix!

Suppose you have two variables :

```
x = tf.Variable(np.random.random_sample(), dtype=tf.float32)
y = tf.Variable(np.random.random_sample(), dtype=tf.float32)
```

and a function defined using these 2 variables:

```
f = tf.pow(x, cons(2)) + cons(2) * x * y + cons(3) * tf.pow(y, cons(2)) + cons(4) * x + cons(5) * y + cons(6)
```

where:

```
def cons(x):
    return tf.constant(x, dtype=tf.float32)
```

So in algebraic terms, this function is

[image]

Now we define a method that compute the hessian:

```
def compute_hessian(fn, vars):
    mat = []
    for v1 in vars:
        temp = []
        for v2 in vars:
            # computing derivative twice, first w.r.t v2 and then w.r.t v1
            temp.append(tf.gradients(tf.gradients(f, v2)[0], v1)[0])
        temp = [cons(0) if t == None else t for t in temp] # tensorflow returns None when there is no gradient, so we replace None with 0
        temp = tf.pack(temp)
        mat.append(temp)
    mat = tf.pack(mat)
    return mat
```

and call it with:

```
# arg1: our defined function, arg2: list of tf variables associated with the function
hessian = compute_hessian(f, [x, y])
```

Now we grab a tensorflow session, initialize the variables, and run `hessian`  :

```
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
print sess.run(hessian)
```

Note: Since the function we used is quadratic in nature (and we are differentiating twice), the hessian returned will have constant values irrespective of the variables.

The output is :

```
[[ 2.  2.]
[ 2.  6.]]
```

Comment: Warning, dear reader: this example only works when `vars`'s contents contain single floats. If any is a vector, matrix, or higher dimensional Tensor, this code will fail.

Instead, use `tf.hessians`, which will compute the portion of the Hessian  relating to each variable in `vars` (so long as each variable is a vector). If you want the FULL Hessian (including all pairwise interactions between variables), you'll need to to start with a single super-vector containing every variable you care about, then slice from there.

Answer (score 1):

A word of caution: Hessian matrices (or more generally, tensors) are expensive to compute and store. You may actually re-think if you really need the full Hessian, or just *some hessian properties*. A number of them, including traces, norms, and top eigen-values can be obtained *without explicit hessian matrix*, just using the Hessian-vector product oracle. In turn, hessian-vector products can be implemented efficiently (also in leading autodiff frameworks such as Tensorflow and PyTorch)